# Проблема с hide() в jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

здраствуйте! у меня прозьба тыкнуть мне носом почему у меня не работает функция hide(). спасибо.

```
function addToCart(itemId){
    console.log("js - addToCart");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST', 
        async: false, 
        url: "/cart/addtocart/" + itemId + '/', 
        dataType: 'json', 
        succes: function (data){

                    if (data['success']){
                        $("#cartCntItems").html(data['cntItem']);

                        $("#addCart_"+itemId).hide();
                        $("#removeCart_"+itemId).show(); 
                    }
                }
    });                                                                                                                 
}
```

Comment: С виду всё ок. Проверьте, есть ли элемент `"#addCart_"+itemId`

Comment: @lampa данный элемент есть "#addCart_"+itemId  , значения его id="addCart_7"
почему не работает не пойму библиотеку подключил норм 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/main.js"></script>  

может ещё есть идеи?

Comment: А в этот if (data['success']){ он заходит?

Comment: @Vitaliisss возможно в коле присутствуют другие ошибки, из-за которых не работает данный код. Также возможно, что ответ приходит не в формате `json`. Что говорит дебаггер браузера? Вставьте `console.log` в условие `data['success']`

Comment: извените за тупость в  "succes"  пропустил s. 
Извените.

Comment: @Vitaliisss ха! Это лечится только временем и опытом)